# Jackson - Don't use @JsonProperty with @JsonPOJOBuilder or @JsonCreator ctor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Preconditions:

> - Java/Spring Boot
> - `PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy` is set
> - DTO classes fields are camel case
> - Json fields are upper camel case
> - DTO/Json field names are aligned
> - Keep DTO classes immutable, avoiding the use of setters for fields

Requirement:

> - Deserialize without using `@JsonProperty` in DTO class (implicitly)

Tried to use nested builder class with `@JsonPOJOBuilder` or constructor, annotated with `@JsonCreator`, however:

- `@JsonPOJOBuilder` annotated Builder class without `@JsonPropery` on `setField()` methods - `setField()` methods not being called by Jackson on
  deserialization
- Constructor with `@JsonCreator` annotation - explicitly requires `@JsonProperty` on parameters

Comment: I just want to know if this is possible, i.e accepting impossible answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a [blog post](https://manosnikolaidis.wordpress.com/) with a solution for this. In summary:

1. use Java 1.8
2. compile with -parameters argument
3. use and register jackson-module-parameter-names

The above will result in Jackson finding the names of the arguments of the constructor in the bytecode without requiring either `@JsonCreator` or `@JsonProperty` on the constructor.

Regardig the naming strategy you can easily set it at [applications.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and although I haven't tested it, should work with the non-annotated constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When using @JsonCreator use camel case.

I used snake case in below example.
@JsonCreator
public ApiResponseBuilder(@JsonProperty("status_code")int statusCode,                               @JsonProperty("status_message")String statusMessage) {